# Simulate window main while in Response - Powerbuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

Is it possible to simulate window main while window response is active? I want my code in window main running.

Comment: What do you mean 'simulate window main'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need a popup window instead of a response window. Response windows are modal and will halt the execution of any code in your main window.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by passing a reference to your main window when you open the response window. See the OpenWithParm function in the help. This is not very good from an object-oriented perspective because in PowerBuilder all of the controls and events in the window are public. It would be best to put the code you want to run in a non-visual object that the window uses and pass a reference to that object.